# Array data is traversed in a wrong way Python/Matlab

Tags: python, c++, matlab, opencv, hdf5

I'm saving a binary OpenCV Mat to a HDF5 file.
In OpenCV Mat files are stored in memory with first index channel, second index is x-Coordinate and third index is y-Coordinate, so an address access looks like:

```
address = M.data + M.step[0]*y + M.step[1]*x + ch
```

Where M.step[0] = NUM_X*NUM_CH and M.step[1] = MAX_CH
The problem I experience is, that Matlab and Python interpret the data in a wrong way.
Though the dimensions of the read data are set correctly (channel, x, y), when I look into the data storage I see, that e.g. numpy reads the data backwards, meaning first y is incremented, then x and lastly the channel number, which means, that it assumes planar configuration of the channel data, while it is actually interleaved. This results in wrong displaying of images.
Is there a way to tell numpy/Matlab to change the data access, without reordering the data?
Thanks in advance.
**Edit:**
I store everything in a rank 3 dataset in the hdf5 file, where dimension 1 is channel, dimension 2 is x-coordinate and dimension 3 is y-coordinate.
If I read that dataset and process it with OpenCV in C++ the correct image is being displayed. OpenCV in python doesn't work because of error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat

Comment: How are you reading it into Python? You could create a custom numpy dtype to read into. One of the meetups I go to recently had a talk on using custom numpy datatypes to read in arbitrary data, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/desertpy/presentations/blob/master/numpy-datatypes-godber/Numpy_Dtypes.ipynb). Maybe that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the question in python by changing the shape and stride of the array, which had been calculated in a wrong way:
If i had a 3*1280*720 uint8 Image with 3 being channel number, 1280 being x-coordinate and 720 being y-coordinate, I would have to assign the shape, so it would look like data.shape = (720, 1280, 3) and the stride would have to be changed to data.strides = (3*1280,3,1).

This link explains how numpy arrays work in memory:
[Numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray)